# Selenium IDE - How to wait for options by name in a select to be populated?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am working with Selenium IDE and on my webapp I have a select of the type:

```
<option value="34">Badge</option>
<option value="38">Bodywork</option>
<option value="1">Category 1</option>
<option value="36">Window</option>
```

I need to wait for an option to be populated in the select using name/text option (e.g.: 'Badge') instead of value/id (e.g.: '34'), before proceeding.

My idea is to use `waitForElementPresent` function, but for test I used `assertElementPresent` when options were already populated.

I have tried this:

```
assertElementPresent
css=select[id='cbo_Subcategory'] option[name='Badge']
```

and this

```
(...) option[text='Badge']
(...) option[label='Badge']
(...) option[name=Badge]
(...) option[text=Badge]
(...) option[label=Badge]
```

but it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: You can not find element using `cssSelector` with visible text here..try using `xpath` as `//select[@id='cbo_Subcategory']/option[text()='Badge']`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's not mandatory then you can use `css`, only then you can try using `xpath` as below :-

```
//select[@id='cbo_Subcategory']/option[text()='Badge']
```

Hope it works..:)